# c++ operator < overloading how to use?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to do a for loop on values of a `std::map` called `ORIGIN` shown below from a lower value to the upper value:
I need to overload the `<` operator in order to do it.

```
myclass
{
    typedef std::vector<tactics*> origin_of_tactics;
    typedef map<float, origin_of_tactics, CompareFloat> ::iterator iter_type;
    iter_type it;
    map<float, origin_of_tactics, CompareFloat> ORIGIN;


    for (it = ORIGIN.find(low_value_in_bar); it <= ORIGIN.find(high_value_in_bar); it++)
    {

    }

} // end of myclass
```

I saw an example for overloading an operator and I tried to change it but I´m not sure how to use it in my class.
and if its the correct way to do it:

```
class Complex
{
    public:
        typedef std::vector<tactics*> origin_of_tactics;
        typedef map<float, origin_of_tactics, CompareFloat>::iterator iter_type;
        bool Complex::operator <(const iter_type &other);
        Complex(iter_type value) : it1(value)
        {};
        bool operator <(const Complex &other);

    private:
        iter_type it1;

};
bool Complex::operator <(const iter_type &other)
{
    if ((it1->first) < (other->first))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

How to do it? and how to write it in a general way for any type of MAP iterator < comparison?
Thanks

Comment: 1) your map has `float` keys. 2) you pass a comparison function to it. So you do not need any comparison operator in your class.

Comment: `I want to do a for loop on **values** of a std::map` - maybe a data type other than map would be better suited

Comment: @djf `std::map` is a sorted container, the elements are always sorted by the index using the given comparison operator. You can iterate over the (sorted) elements simply using the iterators `begin()` and `end()`. What's your problem ?

Comment: Minor: "TRUE" and "FALSE" aren't bool values, use 'true' and 'false' instead.

Comment: Major: `iter_type it;` storing iterators in a class instance is very likely going to cause you pain at this stage in your understanding of the language, I would strongly discourage you from doing it.

Comment: @zakinster The problem is that he doesn't want to iterate over the keys, he wants to iterate over the values. Moreover defining a custom comparer for float keys is nonsense. Right?

Comment: @djf A custom `float` comparison operator may be useful to add some *epsilon* in the comparison. Also I don't see the difference between iterating over the keys or over the values. Since a `std::map` element is just a `pair<key, value>`, you're iterating over both.

Comment: @zakinster I see your point and I agree with you. You iterate over `pair<key,value>` but they're sorted by key. The OP asked how to sort by values - I'm starting to suspect that that wasn't what he meant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a comment but I wanted the code to be readable.

```
myclass
{
    typedef std::vector<tactics*> origin_of_tactics;
    typedef map<float, origin_of_tactics, CompareFloat> ::iterator iter_type;
    iter_type it;
    map<float, origin_of_tactics, CompareFloat> ORIGIN;


    for (it = ORIGIN.find(low_value_in_bar); it <= ORIGIN.find(high_value_in_bar); it++)
    {
    }
} // end of myclass
```

You should start by cleaning this up a little:

```
class myclass
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<tactics*> origin_of_tactics;
    typedef map<float, origin_of_tactics> origins;

    origins ORIGIN;
    // Do NOT store the iterator *value* as a class instance variable
    // it will burn you with fire at this stage in learning C++.
    // The typedef is a good idea for when you have to explicitly state
    // the type, especially if you don't have access to C++11s "auto".
    typedef origins::iterator origin_iter;

    // assuming you want to specify a subset of the values.
    void somefunction(float low_value_in_bar, float high_value_in_bar)
    {
        auto start = ORIGIN.lower_bound(low_value_in_bar);
        auto end   = ORIGIN.upper_bound(high_value_in_bar);
        for (auto it = start; it != end; ++it)
        {
            ....
        }
    }

    // otherwise, since you're using map and it's an ordered container
    void somefunction()
    {
        for (auto it = ORIGIN.begin(); it != ORIGIN.end(); ++it)
        {
            ....
        }
    }

    // or, using new C++11 for
        for (auto& oot : ORIGIN)
        {
           // (oot is of type origin_of_tactics)
        }
} // end of myclass
```

You don't need to overload operator< because it's keyed on a standard type.

The code in your question makes it look like you are keeping iterators in class-member variables rather than as local variables to your function. Try to avoid that (member variable iterators): it's going to bite you and hard, because iterators are complex types with a finite lifespan. Keeping their definition local to their use makes it a lot easier to track down causes of them becoming invalid. Always treat iterators as temporary and transient.

```
std::vector<int> v = { 5, 3, 1 };
auto it = v.begin();
cout << "*it = " << *it << endl;
...
v.push_back(10);
// vector just got bigger and is no-longer in the same location,
// but "it" still points to the old location.
v[0] = 90;
cout << "*it = " << *it << endl; // probably crashes, but won't print 90.
```

The "auto" keyword is a new C++11 keyword which says "figure out what this should be for me" that can be used in local variable declaration:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::array<int, 5> > foo;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::array<int, 5> >::iterator it = foo.begin();
```

can be replaced with

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::array<int, 5> > foo;
auto it = foo.begin();
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/auto

Comment: Hi kfsone, 1)why do you use "auto"?    2) I want to go inside the loop also in the case that it == ORIGIN.end() , in case I use != it will not go into the loop in the case of ==    3) if I don´t put the iterator as class members, I need to write them each time as e.g. origins::iterator, what is the reason that you prefer not to write the iterators as class members?, Thanks

Comment: The typedef is perfectly fine - advisable even. But actually storing it is not because iterators can become invalid. I'll edit the reply to explain.

Comment: I meant I want to go inside the loop also in the case that  it == ORIGIN.find(high_value_in_bar)

Comment: Ok - the code in your question made it look like the iterator was being defined as a class member and not a function-local variable :)

Comment: @user2162793 upper_bound will work equivalent to your original code, because it finds the next iterator *after* the matching value or end, that is, the first iterator that *would* be >= high_bar_value.

Answer (score 0):

First, your comparison operator should compare two instances of `Complex`, could be written :

```
bool Complex::operator<(const Complex&  other) {
    return (this->it1->first) < (other.it1->first);
}
```

Secondly, you don't seem to need that operator to do what you want. The elements of a `std::map<float, origin_of_tactics, CompareFloat>` will already be sorted by the `float` key using the comparator `CompareFloat` (or the default `operator<` if not specified).

You can iterate over the *always* sorted values like this :

```
map<float, origin_of_tactics, CompareFloat> origin;
for (iter_type it = origin.begin(); it != origin.end(); ++it)
{
    ...
}
```

And if you want to iterate over a subset of the map's indexes, you can use [`std::map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) and [`std::map::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound) :

```
float beginIndex, endIndex;
iter_type begin = origin.lower_bound(beginIndex);
iter_type end = origin.upper_bound(endIndex);
for (iter_type it = begin; it == end; ++it)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why would this be necessary to find entries in a map with `float` keys?

Comment: @juanchopanza I also don't get what the class `Complex` is used for.

Comment: Right, basically the code in the question makes no sense at all.

Comment: Hi zakinster, 1) I was not sure how to write it in the same class, this is the reason I used the Complex class. 2) regarding the answer: for (iter_type it = origin.begin(); it != origin.end(); ++it) How do I get inside the loop in the case of it == origin.end() ? Thanks

Comment: @user2162793 `origin.end()` does not point to any element of the map, it refers to the theoretical [*past the end* element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end), if `origin.begin()==origin.end()` it means your map is empty. So you don't want to go inside the loop it `it == origin.end()`.

Comment: Hi  juanchopanza, regarding your comment, why not? floats can not be MAP keys?

Comment: Hi zakinster, I am refering to the end of the subset in the MAP, I am trying to do a for loop on a subset of the MAP values, I used the "end" as in kfsone answer auto start = ORIGIN.lower_bound(low_value_in_bar);
        auto end   = ORIGIN.upper_bound(high_value_in_bar);

Comment: @user2162793 In that case, `end = origin.upper_bound(...)` will point to the last element of the subset of the map, so your stop condition would be `it == end`.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
bool Complex::operator <(const iter_type &other);
// ...
bool Complex::operator <(const iter_type &other);
```

The first problem is that you're attempting to prototype the function twice. The other problem is that when you're inside the class you don't need `Complex::` when declaring a member function. Go with the second one.

zakinster's answer covers the rest.